# Custom stored procedure in Teradata SQL

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant, teradatasql

In the past I adapted a cursor I have in a stored procedure on SQL Server to Teradata but I'm having some troubles trying to use. My procedure code is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_QrRnTables()

BEGIN

DECLARE varTableOldName VARCHAR(500);
DECLARE varTableNewName VARCHAR(500);
DECLARE vardbName VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE varIDCod VARCHAR(5);
DECLARE varRename VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE varCt INT DEFAULT 0;
    
DECLARE renameTables CURSOR 
FOR
    
    SELECT
        nomeDB
        ,nomeTabela
    FROM (
        SELECT
            DatabaseName AS nomeDB
            ,TableName AS nomeTabela
            ,LastAccessTimeStamp AS dtUltimoAcesso
            ,(CURRENT_DATE - CAST(LastAccessTimeStamp AS DATE)) AS diasSemAcesso
        FROM
            DBC.TablesV
        WHERE
            1=1
            AND TableKind = 'T'
            AND DatabaseName IN ('P_BACKUP')
        GROUP BY
            DatabaseName
            ,TableName
            ,LastAccessTimeStamp
            ,LastAlterTimeStamp
    ) tbHig
    WHERE diasSemAcesso IS NULL OR diasSemAcesso >= 180
    ORDER BY nomeDB, nomeTabela

FOR READ ONLY;

OPEN renameTables;

    FETCH NEXT FROM renameTables INTO vardbName, varTableOldName;

    WHILE (SQLCODE = 0)
    
        DO
        
        SET varTableNewName = vardbName || '.' || vardbName || '_V' || CAST(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS VARCHAR(20)) || '_' || CAST(varCt AS VARCHAR(20));
    
        SET varTableOldName = vardbName || '.' || varTableOldName;
    
        SET varRename = 'RENAME TABLE ' || varTableOldName || ' TO ' || varTableNewName;
        
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE varRename;
    
        SET varCt = varCt + 1;
    
        FETCH NEXT FROM renameTables INTO vardbName, varTableOldName;
        
    END WHILE;

CLOSE renameTables;

END;
```

The goal is is to collect the names of a series of tables and rename them using the cursor logic. Something like this: If I have three tables on my database "myTableA", "myTableB", "myTableC", by the cursor logic I hope these are renamed to "P_BACKUP_V2021_0", "P_BACKUP_V2021_1", "P_BACKUP_V2021_2".

The problem happens when I try to call the procedure. Only the first line of execution works and then an error is apparently returned when the cursor tries to continue its execution:

```
Executed as Single statement. Failed [3722 : HY000] SP_QRRNTABLES:Only a COMMIT WORK or null statement is legal after a DDL Statement.
Elapsed time = 00:00:05.668
 
STATEMENT 1: Unknown failed.
```

Maybe the problem is with some syntax details, but I can't see what might be wrong.

Can anyone guide me with this please?

Comment: You're running this Proc in a ANSI-mode session. This requires to commit each DDL, add `commit;`; after the create. Or compile and run the SP in a Teradata mode session, then DDL is autocommited.

Comment: Unfortunately COMMIT will close the outer cursor. In this case it's probably better to use Teradata mode session to create and execute the SP.

Comment: A Queue Table could also be useful. Then instead of an outer cursor you could SELECT AND CONSUME from the queue. Just don't forget to check whether the queue is empty before trying to CONSUME, or the SP will sit and wait for new input.